# Возможно ли из Android приложения узнать откуда оно было скачано?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Можно ли каким то образом узнать откуда приложение было скачано? Получить ссылку внутри приложения?

Answer (score 1):

`PackageManager` предоставляет метод [`getInstallerPackageName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29). Если приложение было скачано с GooglePlay, то этот метод вернет строку `"com.android.vending"`.